# Urns, balls, and simplifying an infinite series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Consider a large number of urns and a large number of people each randomly placing $n \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ balls in urns (people do not place multiple balls in the same urn). Urns receiving multiple balls pick a ball at random. If an individual's balls are chosen by multiple urns, then the individual randomly chooses an urn and we call that a match. Letting z denote the probability that person i is chosen by urn j, conditional on placing a ball in j, I conjecture that the probability that an urn that has chosen a ball forms a match with that ball is given by:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1} \left( \frac{\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}}{n!} \right)\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} z^k(1-z)^{n-1-k}\left(\frac{1}{k+1} \right) \right]$$

Simplifying the expression inside of the brackets yields

$$ \frac{(1-z)^{n-1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
 {n \choose k+1}\left( \frac{z}{1-z} \right)^k $$

This is close to a familiar looking series for the inner brackets, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions or references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying the expression inside of the brackets:

$\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} z^k(1-z)^{n-1-k}\left(\frac{1}{k+1} \right) \right]\tag1$

Using the fact that $\frac{1}{k+1}=\int\limits_0^1 t^kdt$ and replace the order the sum and integral we get:

$\int\limits_0^1\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} (zt)^k(1-z)^{n-1-k}dt\tag2$

According to Binomial formula we can write:

$\int\limits_0^1 (zt+1-z)^{n-1}dt=[\frac{(zt+1-z)^n}{zn}]_{t=0}^1=\frac{1}{zn}-\frac{(1-z)^n}{zn}\tag3$

So the result of the sum inside the brakets is:

$\frac{1}{zn}-\frac{(1-z)^n}{zn}\tag4$

Regarding the whole expression:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}}{n!}\big(\frac{1}{zn}-\frac{(1-z)^n}{zn}\big)\tag5$

Using the same trick as in (2) we have:

$\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{z}\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{t}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\big(t^n-t^n(1-z)^n\big)\tag6$

Known that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}-1;$ we can form the(5) in the following way:

$\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{z}\int\limits_0^1 \big(\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{t}-\frac{e^{\lambda t(1-z)}}{t}\big)dt \tag7$

This integral can be solved by using the integral functions.

Comment: This is a nice solution, for sure. I did not work the problem but I wonder if, once  the expression inside brackets has been fully simplified (this eliminates  the summation over $k$), we could not do the same using the complete and incomplte  gamma functions. By the way, $+1$. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, Thank you, and regards.

Comment: @JV.Stalker Thanks so much. Can you explain what you mean when you write "this integral can be solved by using the integral functions"? Also, I presume this cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but is there an approximation that can? Thanks again.

Comment: @John, Sorry I leave out the "exponential" expression from my sentence. Accordace with Wolfram Alpha the last integral equal to: $\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{z}\big(Ei(\lambda t)-Ei(\lambda t(z-1))\big)|_0^1=\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{z}\Big(\ln(1-z)+\Gamma(0,\lambda(z-1))-\Gamma(0,\lambda)\Big)$ what was seen by Claude Leibovici in advance. The approximation could be a nother exercise, I start to learn this topic. Best regards,